# Image Classification on Photos From Camera?

Tags: classification, change-detection

I have some photos of 1X1 meter plots that were taken with a NIR digital camera. They have been georeferenced, corrected, etc.

I am interested in performing an image classification for the vegetation, however, I have only ever done this on a landscape scale with Landsat, MODIS, or on the scale of a small city-sized area.

I know the vegetation types, I just have a lot of photos and from multiple years and need to train the model to automate the process. I will most likely be utilizing the NDVI, which I am familiar with.

Does anyone know of any journal articles, tutorials, other resources, other feeds where this has been addressed etc. where others have done image classifications/change analyses on as small a scale as a meter squared plot?

Answer (score -1):

Check out this one: http://www.samplepoint.org/

I have not used it but it sounds like exactly what you are looking for. Here is a link to the tutorial document: http://www.samplepoint.org/SamplePointTutorial.pdf

I guess this solution only works if you are interested in using different software than you have used for large scale projects.

Comment: also there are lots of papers referenced on the main page that you may be able to make use of.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/RegionOfInterestTool.html

https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/Classification.html

using ENVI software your objective might be achieved.